# Android onDraw only take changes on second drawing

Tags: android, draw

I am developing drawing module for my app. All features working fine. The problem is, everytime when I change the color, or set the brushSize or change to eraser, the first touch on the screen will draw with the previous settings. The second touch then will have the newest changes. Same goes to undo. Nothing change on first click. For second click and so on, it is working fine. This is my [reference](http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/android-canvas-painting-demo/). The sample app in the reference also has the same problem. This is my code:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {



//drawing path
private Path drawPath;
private Point pointDraw;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
//brush sizes
private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
//private int defaultBrush = 10;
//erase flag
private boolean erase=false;
private int tempColor;
private boolean checkDraw = false;
private ArrayList<PathPoints> paths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
private ArrayList<PathPoints> undonePaths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
private ArrayList<Point> tempCanvas = new ArrayList<Point>();
private int countPoint = 0;
int x,y;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

//setup drawing
private void setupDrawing(){

    //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
    //brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);


    paths.add(new PathPoints(drawPath, paintColor, brushSize, false));
    drawCanvas = new Canvas();
}

//size assigned to view
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

}

//draw the view - will be called after touch event
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    //canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);

    for (PathPoints p : paths) {
        drawPaint.setColor(p.getColor());
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.getStrokeSize());
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), drawPaint);

    }
    setCheckDraw(true);
}


public int getArr()
{
    return paths.size();
}

public boolean isCheckDraw() {
    return checkDraw;
}

public void setCheckDraw(boolean checkDraw) {
    this.checkDraw = checkDraw;
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    drawPath.reset();
    drawPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        drawPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    drawPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    drawPath = new Path();
    paths.add(new PathPoints(drawPath, paintColor, brushSize, false));

}

//register user touches as drawing action
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    //respond to down, move and up events

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            touch_start(touchX, touchY);
            invalidate();

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            touch_move(touchX, touchY);

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            touch_up();
            //invalidate();

        break;
    }
    //redraw
    invalidate();//do not call frequently
    return true;
}

public void validateDraw()
{
    invalidate();
}


//update color
public void setColor(String newColor){
    //invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}

public void setColor(int newColor){
    //invalidate();
    paintColor = newColor;
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    tempColor = paintColor;
}

//set brush size
public void setBrushSize(float newSize){
    float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
            newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    brushSize=pixelAmount;
}

//get and set last brush size
public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize){
    lastBrushSize=lastSize;
}
public float getLastBrushSize(){
    drawPath.reset();
    return lastBrushSize;
}

//set erase true or false

public void setErase(boolean isErase)
{
    //drawPath.reset();
    erase=isErase;
    if(erase)
        this.setColor("#FFFFFFFF");
    else
        //drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
        this.setColor(tempColor);
}



//// new drawing
public void startNew(){
    //drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    paths.clear();
    undonePaths.clear();
    invalidate();
}


public void onClickUndo() {
    if (paths.size() > 0) {
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {

    }

    // toast the user
}

public void onClickRedo() {
    if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
        paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {

    }
    // toast the user
}
```

Thank in advance